# Still have error even though ADT has been updated for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I launch Eclipse, I got error as `"This SDK requires ADT Version 23.0.0." "Current version is ADT 22"`. Then I go to `Eclipse help->Installed Softwre update`, then add the site `"http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"` Then update the software, but the message comes out as Software being installed. Since being installed, why I still have the message `"This SDK requires ADT Version 23.0.0."` when Eclipse is launched. How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Give a search on stackoverflow and search on google android developer forum you will find the answer

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Comment: Uninstall the previous version and install the latset version.

Comment: Thanks I am trying now. It makes me to have extra work